# System.out.print on Android

Tags: android-emulator, console

Using Eclipse I was testing a simple app by running it on a device emulator. The application itself was working fine. I just had a thought of displaying some text on the console by means of System.out.print.

My app is merely a single instance of the Activity class. I imported java.lang.*. For some reason, I was unable to display any text on the console with this: System.out.print("Hello"); 
Also, the Eclipse editor kept showing a warning that java.lang.* was never used!

Was I doing something wrong? Or, does the Dalvik VM require something different from a Java VM when it comes to outputing text on the console?

Thank you.

Comment: If I remember correctly, System.Out.Print("whatever") will print in Eclipse to the Output window. If you want something to print to the screen of your emulator / device, you will need to use a Toast or a similar dialog popup.

Answer (score 0):

There is no console like in Java. If you want to print debug information, use "logcat"
You can view these in eclipse.
If you have ever used i.e. the python logging module, the syntax will be familiar to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not familiar with python logging. If Android uses a trimmed version of the standard Java API, should it not exclude the packages in that API that it does not use? I had seen System.out.print in Android's version of the standard Java API which put in mind the thought of using it in the first place.

Comment: I have tried this: Log.d("Testing: ", "something");
The extra thing I have had to do is make use of one of the filter options on the Logcat tab. I have filtered by the tag which, in my case, is Testing:

Comment: Yep, I think the reason it had System.out.* is because you can redirect the stdout to a file etc... I *think* in debug mode, the standard output is redirected by default to logcat of type "info" anyway but dont take my word for it.